# CakePHP 3 Error: The application is trying to load a file from the DebugKit plugin

Tags: php, symfony, cakephp, heroku, cakephp-3.0

My CakePHP 3 app runs fine on my local server. But when I install it on Heroku, I keep getting the following error:

`Error: The application is trying to load a file from the DebugKit plugin.
Make sure your plugin DebugKit is in the /app/plugins/ directory and was loaded.`

I'm confused because I already did `composer install`, and I see debug_kit in `vendor/cakephp/debug_kit` but the error seems to be looking in the other plugins directory.

Why is this happening?

Update: I ran `composer install --verbose` and I see the following error:

`$ composer install --verbose
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Analyzed 91 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 165 rules to resolve dependencies
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files`

> post-autoload-dump: Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller::postAutoloadDump
>   post-install-cmd: App\Console\Installer::postInstall

```
Script App\Console\Installer::postInstall handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception



  [InvalidArgumentException]                            
  Maximum number of attempts must be a positive value.  



Exception trace:
 () at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Question/Question.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question->setMaxAttempts() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/IO/ConsoleIO.php:246
 Composer\IO\ConsoleIO->askAndValidate() at /app/src/Console/Installer.php:55
 App\Console\Installer::postInstall() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:211
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->executeEventPhpScript() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:167
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:92
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:342
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:131
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:146
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:82
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///app/.heroku/php/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /app/.heroku/php/bin/composer:25


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

The error appears to be coming from Symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this once and believe I fixed it by replacing `App\Console\Installer` with a newer version.

This commit that fixes it traces back to this issue: https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/241

(You might take this opportunity to upgrade other files in your app that came from the template.)

Comment: Thanks! What's the most efficient way to do upgrade the files, as you recommended? It appears CakePHP is still on v3.0 so `composer update` won't work right?

Comment: Btw... I updated `App\Console\Installer` and now `composer install` runs without error. But strangely, the DebugKit error is still there. :-(

Comment: Unfortunately it's a manual process of overwriting all your existing files and going through each change manually (use `git add --patch` to help with this). Regarding the error, running `composer dump-autoload` should update `vendor/cakephp-plugins.php` with the correct plugin path.

Comment: I ran `composer dump-autoload` and it seemed to work. I then re-ran `composer install`. Composer still seems to be working without errors, but I'm still seeing the DebugKit plugin error. Very strange.